# Query uses temporary table without force index

Tags: mysql, indexing

Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE contacts.id,
       contacts.date_modified contacts__date_modified
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT tst.team_set_id
   FROM team_sets_teams tst
   INNER JOIN team_memberships team_membershipscontacts ON (team_membershipscontacts.team_id = tst.team_id)
   AND (team_membershipscontacts.user_id = '5daa2e92-c347-11e9-afc5-525400a80916')
   AND (team_membershipscontacts.deleted = 0)
   GROUP BY tst.team_set_id) contacts_tf ON contacts_tf.team_set_id = contacts.team_set_id
LEFT JOIN contacts_cstm contacts_cstm ON contacts_cstm.id_c = contacts.id
WHERE contacts.deleted = 0
ORDER BY contacts.date_modified DESC,
         contacts.id DESC
LIMIT 21;
```

Takes extremely long (2 minutes on 2M records). **I cant change this query, since it is system generated**

This is it's explain:

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                                                         | key                        | key_len | ref                                       | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | contacts                 | NULL       | ref    | idx_contacts_tmst_id,idx_del_date_modified,idx_contacts_del_last,idx_cont_del_reports,idx_del_id_user | idx_del_date_modified      | 2       | const                                     | 1113718 |   100.00 | Using temporary; Using filesort                                     |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>               | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                                                  | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                                      |       2 |    50.00 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | contacts_cstm            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                                               | PRIMARY                    | 144     | sugarcrm.contacts.id                      |       1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  3 | DERIVED     | team_membershipscontacts | NULL       | ref    | idx_team_membership,idx_teammemb_team_user,idx_del_team_user                                          | idx_team_membership        | 145     | const                                     |       2 |    99.36 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  3 | DERIVED     | tst                      | NULL       | ref    | idx_ud_set_id,idx_ud_team_id,idx_ud_team_set_id,idx_ud_team_id_team_set_id                            | idx_ud_team_id_team_set_id | 144     | sugarcrm.team_membershipscontacts.team_id |       1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But when I use `force index(idx_del_date_modified)`  (which is the same index used in explain), the query takes just 0.01s and I get slightly different explain.

```
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                    | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                              | key                        | key_len | ref                                       | rows    | filtered | Extra                                                               |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | contacts                 | NULL       | ref    | idx_del_date_modified                                                      | idx_del_date_modified      | 2       | const                                     | 1113718 |   100.00 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>               | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                                                                       | NULL                       | NULL    | NULL                                      |       2 |    50.00 | Using where                                                         |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | contacts_cstm            | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                    | PRIMARY                    | 144     | sugarcrm.contacts.id                      |       1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
|  2 | DERIVED     | team_membershipscontacts | NULL       | ref    | idx_team_membership,idx_teammemb_team_user,idx_del_team_user               | idx_team_membership        | 145     | const                                     |       2 |    99.36 | Using index condition; Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DERIVED     | tst                      | NULL       | ref    | idx_ud_set_id,idx_ud_team_id,idx_ud_team_set_id,idx_ud_team_id_team_set_id | idx_ud_team_id_team_set_id | 144     | sugarcrm.team_membershipscontacts.team_id |       1 |   100.00 | Using index                                                         |
+----+-------------+--------------------------+------------+--------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+---------+-------------------------------------------+---------+----------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The first query uses temporary table and file sort, but the query with `force index` uses just where. Shouldn't the queries be the same? Why is the query with force index so much faster - used index is still the same.

Comment: Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57854233/mysql-chooses-completely-wrong-index ?

Answer (score 0):

According to MySQL manual:

> Temporary tables can be created under conditions such as these:
>
> If there is an ORDER BY clause and a different GROUP BY clause, or if
>   the ORDER BY or GROUP BY contains columns from tables other than the
>   first table in the join queue, a temporary table is created.
>
> DISTINCT combined with ORDER BY may require a temporary table.
>
> If you use the SQL_SMALL_RESULT option, MySQL uses an in-memory
>   temporary table, unless the query also contains elements (described
>   later) that require on-disk storage.

Likely, you have better performance because in MySQL there is the query optimizer component.

If you create index the query optimizer could not use the index column even though the index exists. 
Using `force index(..)` you are forcing MySql to use index, instead.

Please consider a detailed example [here](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-index/mysql-force-index/).